# regex is not working in guava

Tags: java, regex, string, split, guava

I am using `guava 21.0` and trying to split a `String` by providing a regex(`\\d`).
However,I am not sure why is not working.

If I change regex to anything which is not regex (eg "a") then it works fine.

Here is the code :

```
public class SplitWithRegex {
    public static Iterable<String> splitByRegex(String string, String regex){
        return Splitter.on(regex).trimResults().omitEmptyStrings().split(string);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Iterable<String> itr = splitByRegex("abc243gca87asas**78sassnb32snb1ss22220220", "\\d");
        for(String s : itr){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Result when regex is applied :

> abc243gca87asas**78sassnb32snb1ss22220220

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: @SergeyProkofiev it should split the string if it finds any digit, as code says.

Comment: @SergeyProkofiev this would not resolve the problem, what is I decide to change the regex later? I have to modify so much code which I think is not a good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use **`Splitter.onPattern("\\d+")`** and not `Splitter.on("\\d+")`.

[Here's](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html#on(java.lang.String)) the javadoc for Splitter's `on` method, this is what it says:

> Returns a splitter that uses the given fixed string as a separator.
>   For example, Splitter.on(", ").split("foo, bar,baz") returns an
>   iterable containing ["foo", "bar,baz"].

So, separator is a treated as `String` literal and not `regex` and hence, it does not split the `String` as expected. If you want regex based splitting then you can use String's `split` method or Splitter's `onPattern` method, e.g.:

```
String[] tokens = "abc243gca87asas**78sassnb32snb1ss22220220".split("\\d+");
for(String token : tokens){
    System.out.println(token);
}

public static Iterable<String> splitByRegex(String string, String regex){
    return Splitter.onPattern(regex).trimResults().omitEmptyStrings().split(string);
}
```

Comment: Or Splitters onPattern(String separatorPattern) method.

Comment: I suppose for the answer with `String.split` you need to use \\d+ to avoid empty token strings.

Comment: From the book **Getting started with google guava** pg no 15, it says "The Splitter class performs the
inverse of the functions of the Joiner class. A Splitter class can split on a single
character, a fixed string, a java.util.regex.Pattern package, a string representing
a regular expression, or a CharMatcher class (another Guava class, which will
be covered in this chapter as well)." Now I am really confused, book is saying regex can be applied and docs saying regex cannot be applied.

Comment: @MehrajMalik The book speaks about the `Splitter` class, not about the `on` method exclusively. If you want regex splitting: `Splitter.onPattern(...)`, if you want literal splitting: `Splitter.on(...)`. The answer could be adapted to make that more visible.